# How to iterate through ModelMultipleChoiceField

Tags: python, django, python-unicode

my modelforms.py looks like:

```
class ChangeEventTimeForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ChangeEventTimeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    events = Event.objects.values

    self.fields['map_area'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MapArea.objects.all(), required=False)
    self.fields['event'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Event.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

class Meta:
    model = ChangeEventTime
    fields = ('map_area', 'time_map', 'event', 'time_event', )
```

and in my models.py there is:

```
event = models.CharField(
    max_length=2000, default=None, blank=True,
)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    print self.event

    if len(self.time_event.__str__()) > 0:
        for obj in self.event:
            print obj
```

Problem is that i can't iterate through self.event. The output for print obj is:

```
[
```

<

E

v

e

n

t

:

a

d

s

a

d

>

,

<

E

v

e

n

t

:

m

i

r

e

k

>

]

What I need is access to that two objects and get some variable. How to do it? I waste whole day and don't know what to do. It looks it is kind of unicode array, I can't call any method on it.

Comment: apparenty `self.event` is a string. Please show the full definition of all model classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have your model field `event` defined as `models.CharField`, it should match what you are trying to do in the form. You need to changed it to

```
events = models.ManyToManyField(Event)
```

In general you shouldn't rely on overriding `save()` to achieve what you want, there's a lot going on with the method so it might cause issues. What I suggest is checking the form instead:

```
# in your views.py
form = ChangeEventTimeForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # here you would have all events in the form
    checked_events = form.cleaned_data['event']
```

Comment: I tried it before but later i have another problem, because m2m relation is created after save is called. I tried post_save signal to get self.event but no luck. Generally i don't save ChangeEventTimeForm instance. I need to determine which Events on checkbox user selects and then do other stuff which i know how to do it.